# AWS Access keys vs keyPairs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am very new to AWS and while getting familiarized with key concepts, I came across two distinct set of `keys` to which I think we could do with either without needing the other.

So the two keys that I want to talk about are

[AWS Access Keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html#access-keys-and-secret-access-keys) and [AWS Key Pairs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#having-ec2-create-your-key-pair). From my understanding Acceskey and secret key are like user name and password which I can use to call CLI and API etc. while Key pair is used for Ssh-ing to my EC2s but what I am still failing to understand is that why did AWS have to create two similar concepts. Why didn't they just keep one pair of keys and have users use them for all the operations?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The use of **public-private keypairs** is standard in the IT industry, especially with Linux-based computers. Anyone who uses Linux in a corporate environment would likely be using keypairs.

**Access Keys and Secret Keys** are the AWS equivalent of a username and password, but for API calls. This is necessary to authenticate to AWS to prove that you are permitted to make the API call.

So, AWS did not "create two similar concepts". One is an industry standard for logging into a computer, the other is used to authenticate to AWS.

Answer (score 1):

It is created to distinguish two types of users,

Access keys are for users who have create and own instance.
Key pairs are for those who are users of ec2 instance.

**Owner** can create multiple key pairs for granting access for users (one for each)

**Users** don't need to share access keys of owner as they don't need to create resources thus maintaining separation of concern.